# Why is this red stuff filling my smoke domain?

Tags: smoke-simulation

Exactly what it sounds like. [image]

File: [image]

Comment: I just checked the file, and for me it only shows up in LookDev view, and not in any renders. It also only shows up on the first frame (0) and not when there's any smoke in the domain. Is it the same for you? It looks to me like a bug in how Blender draws smoke in the LookDev view.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it's only LookDev and the first frame. After that in LookDev there's some floating fire but it's otherwise normal. Guess you're right and it's a bug. Thanks.

Comment: It might not be a bug, could be a setting, but none that I could find.